# Facebook invite in phonegap returns OK

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, cordova

I need to be able to invite friends to my application on Android. I'm using HTML/js with Phonegap. The login with FB is working fine with the plugin but i can't make the invite work.

My code is:

```
FB.ui(
   {method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'test'},
   function(response) {
    alert("res:" + response);
    }
);
```

I can select the friends, it sends the request but in the alert i get "res:OK" instead of the IDs of the friends.
In addition, in order to make it work, i must configure "Website" platform in addition to Android. Is there another way? I want to open specific page in the application for those who already have the application.

My FB settings:

```
Base:
  App Domains: <empty>
Android:
  Package Name: com.milab.idc.sheets
  Class Name: com.milab.idc.sheets.ProjectActivity
Website:
  Site URL: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.milab.idc.sheets
```

My Play store page:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.milab.idc.sheets

Thanks

Comment: I'm facing the exact same thing using Phonegap and FacebookConnect. I'm looking for a solution right now, please if you find one post it, I'll do the same. cheers and good lock to us!

Comment: I am too facing the same issue, any help ???

Comment: Could you give us the output of `console.log(response);`?

Comment: @DorR Forgot to tag you in the comment. Please see my comment above.

Comment: All I get in the response is: "OK"

Answer (score 2):

the [facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.1) say you should populate the `to` parameter with the friends id

`FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests',
        message: 'Come play Friend Smash with me!',
        to: friend_ids
      }, 
      function(){
            //handle result
      }`

it seems like it is missing.

plus you should receive the Refence_id that point on the request and not the friend_id.

Comment: I don't know the ids of the friend I want to invite. That is the whole purpose. The user selects the friends from the Facebook invite popup and it returns the selected Id. That works fine with Facebook js api. Not working when using it with phonegap plugin in phonegap build

Comment: do you have the user_friends permission before making your apprequests ?

it is a requirement in order to receive anything other that an empty list

Comment: Thanks Rugdr, But I already had this permission... As I said, it is working when using the Facebook JS SDK, it just desn;t work when using it via Phonegap facebook plugin

Comment: what did you install just the phonegap plugin? cause you still need the facebook js sdk and apk.

i need to know a bit more about the step you made in order to find what's missing.

Comment: I did reference all the relevant js files. The login process works perfectly. Just the invite window doesn't return the ids of the users who got invited.